# What's the song when Mikasa talks to her squad leader while on the mission helping Eren to seal the wall with a rock in episode 12?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

On season 1 episode 12, there's a song when Mikasa talks to her squad leader while on a mission helping Eren to seal the wall with a rock, as shown on the following picture.

[image: Mikasa talking to her squad leader]

What's that song?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s Vogel im Kafig. It’s on the OST or you can find it on YouTube here: https://youtu.be/M2LdF1RlSL0.